# LotusScript / LotusFormula - how to replace first element of dialog list in lookup formula?

Tags: lotusscript, lotus, lotus-formula

I am using Dialog list field.
It has the computed formula, which is searching some values in view and filling in that values in the dialog list.

My formula:

```
@If(filia!="";
@Unique(filia:@DbLookup("";"";"use_Dovidka_struktura";filia;2;[FailSilent]));
"")
```

But I am trying to delete the first element of this lookup result with only using @formula. The first element always must to be deleted in this task.

Is it real to make this with @formulas and can you give some small example?
Thanks!

p.s. I can't change the type of the field and I need to make this without using LotusScript.

**Update:**

I have changed formula by Knut's advice and it looks like this:

```
 @If(filia!="";
    textlist := @Unique(filia:@DbLookup("";"";"use_Dovidka_struktura";filia;2;[FailSilent]));"");
@If(@Elements(textlist) > 1; @Subset(textlist; - @Elements(textlist) + 1); "")
```

Thanks for your answer Knut Herrmann, I have tried your solution, everything is working fine! Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use `@Subset` to return list without first element:

```
listWithoutFirstElem := @If(@Elements(list) > 1; @Subset(list; - @Elements(list) + 1); "");
```